# How to setup Server to Monitor Resource Usage Over Period of Time & Generate Report

Tags: linux, logging, performance-monitoring

I am working on a research project and we usually start a job on a server and it takes about a day or two to run and then we go and look back at the results. The problem is that in some cases we are starving the server of resources and it is impacting our results since some jobs fail.

I would like to generate a report that we can look back on to determine how server resources were being used and cross-reference that with the job.

I have tried doing this with atop (using its rawfile format) but there are a lot of issues in terms of reading this format on different machines (ie different versions of linux or atop etc etc.)

So I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution? Ultimately I need to be able to drill down into resource consumption on a per-process level, and see the command used to instantiate the process (like the command column in htop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably start with the

```
sar -f /var/log/sysstat/sa6
```

to see yesterday system daya

as well  `vmstat`

that gives you the ability to start narrowing the problems down to the hour. From there you can start looking in the server logs to see if there are errors. Use grep on the logs and look for your process name and keywords like problem, error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `nmon` , you can get it from the EPEL repository.

You can schedule a cron job to create a daily report, for example this would generate a report each morning at 7:

```
- name: nmon cron
  cron:
    name: "Generate nmon daily at 7:00"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "7"
    job: "/bin/nmon -fT -s300 -c290 -m /root/nmon"
    user: root
    cron_file: nmon
```

Reports vary in size, for example first one is from a test server, second one from a Oracle production server:

```
[root@xxxxxx379 ~]# du -sh nmon/xxxxxx379_201108_0700.nmon
316K    nmon/xxxxxx379_201108_0700.nmon

[root@xxxx203 ~]# du -sh nmon/xxxx203_201108_0700.nmon
1.8M    nmon/xxxx203_201108_0700.nmon
```

You can then graph the statistics in a number of ways (output is csv).